# How to Single Sign on Authentication with mail zimbra and sharepoint?

Tags: sharepoint-addin, sso

I need to write a single sign-on login with Zimbra mail account, and SharePoint 2013, please help me :)

Answer (score 0):

You can refer to link below which would provide you basic ideas about Zimbra Authentication and permissions managed through SharePoint.

Also it suggests that **SharePoint Form Based Authentication (FBA)** is not supported for Zimbra Authentication.

https://community.telligent.com/documentation/w/telligent-community-8/41857.zimbra-connect-for-sharepoint-4-1

https://community.telligent.com/documentation/w/telligent-community-8/41861.zimbra-connect-for-sharepoint-4-1-architecture

https://community.telligent.com/documentation/w/telligent-community-85/47500.telligent-connect-for-sharepoint-4-1